# Python pandas column asignment between dataframe and series does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment, series

I have a `df` dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'b':[100,100,100], 'a':[1,2,3]})
df['c'] = pd.np.nan
df['d'] = pd.np.nan
df['c'] = df['c'].astype(object)
df['d'] = df['d'].astype(object)
```

`df` is:

```
   a    b    c    d
0  1  100  NaN  NaN
1  2  100  NaN  NaN
2  3  100  NaN  NaN
```

I want to do a `df.apply()` with my function `func(x)` to set values for columns `c` and `d`.

`func(x)` is:

```
def func(x):
    return pd.Series({'d':{'foo':5, 'bar':10}, 'c':300})
```

`df.apply()` is:

```
df[['d', 'c']] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
```

And the result is:

```
   a    b                      c    d
0  1  100  {'foo': 5, 'bar': 10}  300
1  2  100  {'foo': 5, 'bar': 10}  300
2  3  100  {'foo': 5, 'bar': 10}  300
```

And my question is that why column `c` gets the result from the returning series with index `d`? And how can I achieve the correct column assignment? Of course my function and`apply()` is much more complicated, that's why I use dictionary at `return`. So `df[['c', 'd']] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)` is not a solution to my real problem.

The desired result is:

```
   a    b    c                      d
0  1  100  300  {'foo': 5, 'bar': 10}
1  2  100  300  {'foo': 5, 'bar': 10}
2  3  100  300  {'foo': 5, 'bar': 10}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: You can reorder the columns returned by apply: `df[['d', 'c']] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)[['d', 'c']]` I don't think pandas does label based alignment when assigning the results.

Comment: `df[['c', 'd']] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)` is however a solution to your example problem here, so it's hard to understand what your real problem is.

Comment: @Khris: The problem is that I have 6 returning values in the dictionary, and I can't set the order of the dictionary element (maybe I could use a list to gather the returning values), so I wanted to use the keys of dictionary to identify what dictionary value should be inserted into what column.

Comment: @ayhan: It's a very nice and working solution, thank you!!!

Comment: I see. It seems like you have a solution already, however I recommend checking the `update()`-method. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me works creating new `DataFrame` `df1` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original `df`:

```
def func(x):
    return pd.Series({'d':{'foo':5, 'bar':10}, 'c':300})

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
print (df1)
     c                      d
0  300  {'bar': 10, 'foo': 5}
1  300  {'bar': 10, 'foo': 5}
2  300  {'bar': 10, 'foo': 5}

print (pd.concat([df[['a','b']], df1], axis=1))
   a    b    c                      d
0  1  100  300  {'bar': 10, 'foo': 5}
1  2  100  300  {'bar': 10, 'foo': 5}
2  3  100  300  {'bar': 10, 'foo': 5}
```